# Loop through controls and change LINQ columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have the following code:

```
 Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 20
        Dim captionTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("news_Image" + i.ToString() + "CaptionTextBox"), TextBox)
        Dim deleteCheckBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Image" + i.ToString() + "DeleteCheckBox"), CheckBox)
        If Not deleteCheckBox.Checked = False Then
            If Not captionTextBox.Text = "" Then
                'Insert the value of the textbox into the column like news_Image1Caption, news_image2Caption nased on the value of i
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Where the comment is in the code above, I need to insert the value of the textbox (text) into Linq columns. For example: articleToUpdate.news_Image1Caption, news_Image2Caption, but I need to change the number after news_ to the value of i in the for loop. How can I do this?

Thanks

Luke

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but first let me start by saying that you should try to avoid double negative condition checks (i.e.: If Not deleteCheckBox.Checked = False. That is the same as deleteCheckBox.Checked) It makes your code that much hard for another person to comprehend.

When you say you need to change the number after news_ to the value of "i", are you saying you want to change the name of the control to news_Image & i.ToString?

Comment: Hi, no articleToUpdate is the name of the LINQ query, and then news_Image(number) if the column. There are 20 columns in the database table named news_Image1Caption, news_Image2Caption etc etc. I need to change the number in the middle each time, based on i. So if i = 20, the column should be news_Image20Caption and so on. How can I do this? So visually I would be writing news_Image(i)Caption, but I need a way to do this in vb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to  set the ID column to Auto-Generated Value = true ?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[s_Tbl]([ID], [news_Image1Caption], [news_image2Caption]) VALUES (...)
```